# calling a specific slider directly from the code

Tags: php, wordpress, slider, echo, nivo-slider

I am running a Wordpress website and the theme which I've installed on it, it comes with a nivoSlider which is displayed on the homepage. Right now, I can select which slider to display on the homepage by logging into the WP Dashboard and navigating to the Theme Options panel. From there, I can select which slider to display, on the homepage, from the dropdown (the list keeps on populating as I create more sliders). Here's the code which echos the section for 'Slider' in the theme options panel:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// SLIDER
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

        $options[] = array( "name" => __('SLIDER','gxg_textdomain'),
                                                "type" => "heading",
                                                "img" => "/includes/admin/images/s.png");

        $options[] = array( "name" => __('Set up your slider','gxg_textdomain'),
        "type" => "info");


        $options[] = array( "name" => __('Show Slider on Homepage','gxg_textdomain'),
                                                "id" => $shortname."_slider",
                                                "std" => "1",
                                                "type" => "checkbox");


        $options[] = array( "name" => __('Select a Slider','gxg_textdomain'),
                                                "desc" => __('After you have created a slider, you can select it here.','gxg_textdomain'),
                                                "id" => $shortname."_sliderimages",
                                                "type" => "select",
                                                "options" => $options_slides);
```

And this is the code inside the header.php file which echo's the slider on the homepage:

```
<?php get_template_part( 'slider' ); ?>
```

Now currently, if I put the above code inside any template file to display the slider on that particular template, the only slider displayed is the one which is selected from the Themes Option Panel. Here's the code which is inside the slider.php file:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">



        <?php

                if ( of_get_option('gg_slider') && of_get_option('gg_sliderimages') ) {



                        global $wpdb, $post;



                        $slider = of_get_option('gg_sliderimages');

                        $meta = get_post_meta( $slider, 'gxg_slider_images', false );



                        if ( !is_array( $meta ) )

                                $meta = ( array ) $meta;



                        if ( !empty( $meta ) ) {

                                $meta = implode( ',', $meta );



                                $images = $wpdb->get_col( "

                                        SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts

                                        WHERE post_type = 'attachment'

                                        AND ID IN ( $meta )

                                        ORDER BY menu_order ASC

                                    " );



                                foreach ( $images as $att ) {

                                        // Get image's source

                                        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $att, 'full' );

                                        $src = $src[0];



                                        $caption = get_post_meta( $att , '_slidercaption', true);

                                        $caption = htmlspecialchars($caption, ENT_QUOTES);



                                        $cf = get_post_meta( $att , '_sliderurl', true);



                                        // Show image

                                        if ($cf) {    

                                        echo "<a href='$cf'><img src='{$src}' alt='' title='$caption' /></a>";

                                        } else {    

                                        echo "<img src='{$src}' alt='' title='$caption' />";

                                        }



                                }

                        }        

                }        

        ?>

</div><!-- .slider-->
```

What I basically want to do is that I want to modify the slider.php file in such a way that I can directly input either the ID of the slider or the slug of the slider (inside the slider.php file) so that it's echo'd out regardless of whichever slider I've selected in the Theme Options panel. From what I understand, this might be the code which is selecting the slider based on my selection in the Theme Options panel:

```
$slider = of_get_option('gg_sliderimages');
```

Instead of '`of_get_option('gg_sliderimages')`' in the above code, I was wondering if there's any way I could enter the ID/slug of the slider which I want to display.

Looking forward to a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you want to copy the second part of code to a custom view (example single.php), and echo a custom slider with custom posts which you would have hard typed?

Well, after you have copied the code, you should delete the first conditional which expects parameters from your template options, as you already figured out. That way it will always display the slider, regardless of what you have selected in the menu.

Secondly, comment out this line of code:

```
$slider = of_get_option('gg_sliderimages');
```

You're going to do that because the $slider variable contains an array of post IDs which were forwarded by the custom theme function of_get_option().
After that you will need to define your own array, just as you wanted, an array of custom posts.
Example:

```
$slider[] = array('123', '256', '455');
```

Also, keep in mind that redefining the global variables can break your code down further if for example your single.php file is expecting previously defined $post by query_posts(); in which case you should reset the query after the foreach loop.